# Keypress event in c# to find out the pressed key

Tags: c#, wpf

Am trying to get the content of a textbox whenever enter key is pressed in WPF application.But there is no option for KeyPress.So i used KeyDown event.But each time the control goes to the code behind for every keypress.Is there any efficient alternate for this ?

```
private void txt_chat_KeyDown_1(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Key == Key.Return)
   {
     txt_conversation.AppendText(Environment.NewLine+txt_chat.Text);
   }
   else { return; }
}
```

and my XAML

```
<RichTextBox IsReadOnly="True"
             ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
             x:Name="txt_conversation"
             HorizontalAlignment="Left"
             Height="150"
             Margin="21,21,0,0"
             VerticalAlignment="Top"
             Width="269">
  <FlowDocument>
    <Paragraph>
      <Run Text="RichTextBox" />
    </Paragraph>
  </FlowDocument>
</RichTextBox>
<TextBox ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
         KeyDown="txt_chat_KeyDown_1"
         x:Name="txt_chat"
         HorizontalAlignment="Left"
         Height="84"
         Margin="51,190,0,0"
         VerticalAlignment="Top"
         Width="209">
</TextBox>
```

Comment: Check this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752054.aspx

Comment: I did the same.My question is actually when i have a breakpoint in my codebehind am observing that for each key press the control goes to the server page and the process happens.How can i prevent this

Comment: @suresh server page? - I have no idea what you're talking about. You need an `InputBinding` to a Command in the ViewModel, rather than handling it procedurally in code behind.

Comment: I don't see why going to codebehind each keydown is inefficient (as the code is currently written). The execution of the `if` per keydown seems like it would have negligible impact on user interaction.

Comment: The KeyPress event is named PreviewTextInput in WPF, e.Text gives you the typed character.

Answer (score 0):

Here instead of putting TextBox directly, you can have Button with its `Template` set as TextBox. Here Button is set as `IsDefault` i.e its click event will be fired whenever Enter is pressed and for `TextBox AcceptReturn` is set as False, so whenever Enter key is pressed when Textbox has focus, parent button click event will get fired.
In this way, event will be fired only when Enter key is pressed

```
  <Button x:Name="myButton" IsDefault="True" Click="Button_Click">
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <TextBox AcceptsReturn="False" Text="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
    </Button>
```

And in the Click handler you can get the Text value from the button `Tag` to which `TextBox.Text` was bound.

```
     private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string text = myButton.Tag.ToString();
        txt_conversation.AppendText(Environment.NewLine+text );
    }
```

Comment: That's a really clever use of a button's control template. It feels a bit hacky though, especially with the need for the button to be default.

Comment: just gave the best suited solution to the problem... Else the problem should be fixed by implementing the mvvm and use commands and bindings to do this stuff

Comment: did you find better solution for this?